# painting a particular button from a grid of buttons

Tags: java, swing, repaint, paintcomponent

The following grid of buttons is defined as :

```
JButton button_x = new RoundButton();
```

[image]

where `RoundButton` is defined as :

```
public class RoundButton extends JButton {

    public RoundButton(String label) {
        super(label);
        this.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        Dimension size = this.getPreferredSize();
        size.height = size.width = Math.max(size.height, size.width);
        this.setPreferredSize(size);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if(!GameState.getIfComplete()) { // If the game is not complete or has just started
            this.setBorder(null);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);
            if(this.getModel().isArmed()) {
               g.setColor(Color.RED);
            }else {
                g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
            g.fillOval(0,0,this.getSize().width-1,this.getSize().height-1);
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }else {
            this.setBorder(null);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillOval(0,0,this.getSize().width-1,this.getSize().height-1);
            super.paintComponent(g); 
        }
    }
```

}

Currently all the buttons are painted in green, but on a certain condition I want to paint particular buttons in white (which is the code in the else part).For instance when `!GameState.getIfComplete()` returns `false`  I want to paint the buttons in the  first column in white. So I call `repaint` as :

```
buttons[0].repaint();
buttons[3].repaint();
buttons[6].repaint();
```

But this doesn't work ! With the first column some other buttons are also painted in white. Why is that ?

What is wrong with the call ? How do I paint a particular button ?

Comment: You probably should just be creating colored icons & setting them to a standard button.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I'm sure I've already addressed that calling `this.setBorder(null);` is a horrendously bad idea.  If you don't want a border to ever be set, try overriding the `getBorder` method and return `null` from it

Comment: @MadProgrammer  yeah ! I addressed that too. It just got reflected here.

Comment: @saplingPro No probs, I added a couple of additional ideas as well ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the reliance on the `GameState`, ALL your round buttons use the same logic to paint themselves, that is, when the game is completed, they will all be painted `WHITE`

Instead, you should rely on the properties of the button.  Set it up so that the colors are actually derived from the button itself.

[image][image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class BadButton01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BadButton01();
    }

    public BadButton01() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    public static class GameState {

        private static boolean isComplete;

        public static boolean getIfComplete() {
            return isComplete;
        }

        public static void setComplete(boolean value) {
            isComplete = value;
        }

    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private RoundButton[] btns = new RoundButton[]
        {
            new RoundButton("1"),
            new RoundButton("2"),
            new RoundButton("3"),
            new RoundButton("4"),
            new RoundButton("5"),
            new RoundButton("6"),
            new RoundButton("7"),
            new RoundButton("8"),
            new RoundButton("9")
        };

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
            for (RoundButton btn : btns) {
                add(btn);
            }
            btns[0].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    GameState.setComplete(true);
                    btns[0].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    btns[1].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    btns[2].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public class RoundButton extends JButton {

        public RoundButton(String label) {
            super(label);
            this.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            setBorderPainted(false);
            setFocusPainted(false);
            setOpaque(false);
            Dimension size = this.getPreferredSize();
            size.height = size.width = Math.max(size.height, size.width);
            this.setPreferredSize(size);
            setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
//            if (!GameState.getIfComplete()) { // If the game is not complete or has just started
//                this.setBorder(null);
//                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
//                g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);
                if (this.getModel().isArmed()) {
                    g.setColor(Color.RED);
                } else {
//                    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    g.setColor(getBackground());
                }
//            } else {
//                this.setBorder(null);
//                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
//                g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);
//                g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
//                g.fillOval(0, 0, this.getSize().width - 1, this.getSize().height - 1);
//                g.setColor(getBackground());
//            }
            g.fillOval(0, 0, this.getSize().width - 1, this.getSize().height - 1);
            super.paintComponent(g);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: and why doesn't the call `buttons[btn_number].repaint` doesn't paint only the particular button

Comment: Because that's not how painting works. The repaint manager takes all the repaint request and can combine them all into a single request, which may include other components. Get over the illusion that you control the paint process, you don't, the Repaint!anager does. Check out [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for a more indeepth explanation