# Filling a Jbutton with a circle

Tags: java, swing, colors, grid, geometry

I have a grid layout of `JButton`s that I would like to fill each individual button with a colored circle when clicked. I only know how to fill a `JButton` with text when clicked, how would I go about doing this?

Here is my code, when clicked, instead of using `setText("")` I want to fill that button with a circle.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            for(int r = 0; r < row; r++){
                for(int c = 0; c < col; c++){
                    if (board[row][col] == e.getSource()){
                            int temp = game.dropDiskAt(c);
                            game.dropDiskAt(c);
                            board[temp][c].setText("");
                        }
```

Comment: Well, you could do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846937/painting-a-particular-button-from-a-grid-of-buttons/15847188#15847188) or you could just use an image

Comment: I'm still really confused >.< the code you provided shades in the whole button which happens to be circle shaped, I'm trying to put a colored circle in my grid on the button where I clicked, I'm trying to make a connect 4 game.

Comment: So?  Instead of using `fillOval `, use `drawOval`. Take a look at [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for more details about painting

Comment: I figured it out thank you =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be a solution

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.Icon;

public class ColorIconRound implements Icon {

private int size;
private Paint color;

public ColorIconRound(int size, Paint color) {
    this.size = size;
    this.color = color;
}

@Override
public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    Paint op = g2d.getPaint();
    g2d.setRenderingHint(
        RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setPaint(color);
    g2d.fillOval(x, y, size, size);
    g2d.setPaint(op);
}

@Override
public int getIconWidth() {
    return size;
}

@Override
public int getIconHeight() {
    return size;
}

}
```

Then just set the icon of your button like this:

```
board[temp][c].setIcon(new ColorIconRound(12,Color.WHITE));
```

If you don't like it filled change the `g2d.fillOval` to `drawOval` in the paintIcon metod.

Comment: You've forgot to define the method `getIconHeight()`. Also the closing brace is missed. And method paintIcon should restore the origin color in Graphics object after painting

Comment: Thank you I'll give this a shot, it says I need to implement the abstract method Icon.getIconHeight though, where would i do this?

Comment: Thanks @Sergiy Medvynskyy, the first part was copy and past error, restoring ok added code (even if I sadly never have done this...), you have a java doc link?

Comment: It works thank you so much! I would upvote your post but i don't have enough rep yet...