# Making a Button Class

Tags: java, swing

The issue I am having is figuring out how to link my button class to my main program. I realize I have a lot of methods from external classes so I will try to give an overview. Basically I have an arrayList of quotes and a key created from a random permutation of the alphabet. I use this key to "encrypt" the quote. Via this method:

```
public static String translate ( String text, String key )
    {
        String newText = "";
        for( int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++ )
        {
            char currentLetter = text.charAt( i );
            if( ALPHA.contains( Character.toString( currentLetter ) ) )
            {
                int index = ALPHA.indexOf( currentLetter );
                char newLetter = key.charAt( index );
                newText = newText + text.substring( i, i + 1 ).replace
                    ( currentLetter, newLetter ) ;
            }
            else 
                newText = newText + currentLetter;
        }
        return newText;
    }
```

So what I want to do is to have a button that takes user input and replaces the letters in the quote with that input. I'm not using `JButton`, I'm using a library to make a square and then using `mouseEvent`. I made the button in a separate class here:

```
import wheelsunh.users.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 * Creates a button
 * 
 * @author Scott
 */
public class SubstituteButton extends RoundedRectangle
{   
    String response;

    public SubstituteButton( int x, int y )
    {
        super( x, y );
        super.setSize( 20, 20 );
        super.setFillColor( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );
        super.setFrameColor( Color.BLACK );
    }

   public void mousePressed( MouseEvent e )
   {
       super.setFillColor( new Color( 131,111,255 ) );

       try
       {
       response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Which letter"
            + " would you like to replace? Ex. ab would replace all a's"
            + " with b's" );
       }
       catch( NullPointerException exeception )
       {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "Input Error" );
       }

       super.setFillColor( Color.LIGHT_GRAY );     
   }

   public String getInput()
   {
       if( response.length() == 2 && 
          Character.isLetter( response.charAt( 0 ) ) && 
          Character.isLetter( response.charAt( 1 ) ))
       {
           return response;
       }
       return null;
   }
   public static void main( String args[] )
    {
       new Frame();
       new SubstituteButton( 100, 100 );
   }
}
```

HSo how would I update the displayed quote so that it replaces the letters? I was thinking I could just use the `replace()` method in the button class, but it doesn't update the displayed quote. Here is the main program:

```
import wheelsunh.users.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Character;

/**
 * Displays a quote with letters in blocks and punctuation without blocks.
 * If a letter has been changed from the original then it is highlighted.
 * Displayed lines must be broken to stay on frame.
 * 
 * 
 * @author Scott
 */
public class CryptogramApp extends ShapeGroup
{
    private ArrayList< String > blockQuote;
    private int quoteLength;
    private SubstituteButton substituebutton;
    private boolean newState = true;
    private String key, quote, encryptedQuote;

    /**
     * Creates a block-quote with first letter at initialX,initialY
     * with the text from quote.
     * 
     * @param initialX int
     * @param initialY int
     * @param quote String
     */
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public CryptogramApp( int initialX, int initialY )
    {         
       if( newState == true )
           newQuote();

       int newx = initialX;

       for( int i = 0; i < quote.length(); i++ )
       {
           String letter = Character.toString( encryptedQuote.charAt( i ) );
           BlockLetter b = new BlockLetter( newx, initialY, letter );
           newx += BlockLetter.WIDTH;

           if( letter.equals(" ") && b.getXLocation() > 400 )
           {
               newx = initialX;
               initialY += 40;
           }
       }
       newState = false;

    }
    public void newQuote()
    {
        blockQuote = new ArrayList<String>();
        key = StringUtilities.getRandomKey();
        quote = getRandomQuote();
        System.out.println( key );
        encryptedQuote = StringUtilities.translate( quote, key );
        System.out.println( encryptedQuote );
        substituebutton = new SubstituteButton( 425, 350 );
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
    * Returns the String text with the jth character replaced with key.
    * 
    * @param text String
    * @param key String
    * @param j int
    * 
    * @return String
    */
    public String getRandomQuote()
    {
        Random gen = new Random();
        ArrayList< String > list = StringUtilities.getQuotes();
        String quote = list.get( gen.nextInt( 6 ) );
        return quote;
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /**
     * Runs a simple test of CryptogramApp.
     * 
     * @param args String[]
     */
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        new Frame( 700, 500 );
        new CryptogramApp( 20, 50 );

    }
}
```

Comment: How does the `SubstituteButton` know anything about the `quote` or `key`?  Perhaps you should devise a [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) for the button, where your `CryptogramApp` can register a listener to it, so when it's activated, you can can be notified, this way `CryptogramApp`, which has the `key` and `quote` values

Comment: You've obviously made a decision not to use `JButton` as your base class, which I think you're seriously shooting yourself in the foot over, as all the functionality you're trying to replicate has already been taken care of with it. For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846937/painting-a-particular-button-from-a-grid-of-buttons/15847188#15847188) which uses `JButton` as the base class and simple custom painting to render a different shape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MadProgrammer is clearly correct. Why haven't you subclassed `JButton`??

Now to your code,

It's not clear what error you're receiving, or what is not working for you.

Should you have

```
public class SubstituteButton extends RoundedRectangle implements MouseListener
```

and at some stage

```
SubstituteButton button=new SubstituteButton();
button.addMouseListener(button)
```

? This would connect your button to the listener.

Also, where are you adding the button to the frame?
Please post the complete code.

Comment: I wasn't getting any errors, I'm still learning java and wasn't sure how to get what I watnted. .I realized I should have just used JButton but I already had the code written when I realized it wasn't a very good method. I add the button  in newQuote(). It not a great spot for it and Ill move it after added more functionality. Thank you MadProgrammer and Sanjay, I really appreciate the help.