# How to make a rounded JButton in Java

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I am a relatively new Java programmer. In the attempt to make a strategic checkers game, I came across a problem. I want to make 24 buttons(pieces count) that show moves the user can make when clicked. I want to make the JButton's circular(pieces are circular in Checkers) but I am unable to do so. The questions I have looked at so far all use images or make their own Border's, etc(too complicated for me). I made a new object(for the pieces) that extends JButton. I am hoping for an easy and simple answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: They're not complicated, it's just I would accept those answers, if explained in a right manner. Thanks.

Comment: Well, [that's one approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15846937/painting-a-particular-button-from-a-grid-of-buttons/15847188#15847188) and [that's another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386749/how-to-add-to-this-round-button-metal-background-in-java/13389263#13389263) - although to be honest, using images and configuring the button to have no background/content might be easier